# Getting Zelig to work with lists

Tags: r, plyr, r-zelig

I want to take a list of matched data sets (where observations are being matched on their propensity scores, using the [MatchIt Package](http://gking.harvard.edu/matchit)) for subsequent modelling in the [Zelig Package](http://gking.harvard.edu/zelig).

In this example, there are two treatments I'll match on (`t1` and `t2`), two independent variables (`x1` and `x2`), and an outcome (`y1`).

```
library(Zelig)
library(MatchIt)
library(plyr)

d1 <- data.frame(y1 = rbinom(100, 1, .5),
                 x1 = runif(100),
                 x2 = runif(100),
                 t1 = rbinom(100, 1, .5),
                 t2 = rbinom(100, 1, .5))
```

First, I'll make a list of matched data frames:

```
list.dfs <- llply(c("t1", "t2"), 
                  function(i) 
                  matchit(as.formula(paste0(i, "~ x1 + x2")), data= d1))
```

Just a check--each element of `list.dfs` has the right class:

```
class(list.dfs[[1]])
```

> `[1] "matchit"`

Next, I want to take element matched data frame from this list, and make a list of Zelig model objects

```
list.mods <- llply(list.dfs, 
                   function(i) 
                   zelig(y1 ~ x1 + x2, model = "logit", data = match.data(i)))
```

Which provides the following error:

> `Error in match.data(i) : object 'i' not found`

But this is clearly something to do with the list, since everything works if I do the same function to a single element of `list.dfs`:

`class(zelig(y1 ~ x1 + x2, model = "logit", data = match.data(list.dfs[[1]])))`

> `[1] "zelig" "logit"`

What am I missing? How can I get Zelig to work on separate items in this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some weird stuff inside `zelig` that looks for the value of `data` by name. Looks like you're going to have to do an explicit loop:

```
list.mods <- list()
for(i in seq_along(list.dfs)) {
    list.mods[[i]] <- zelig(y1 ~ x1 + x2, model = "logit", data = match.data(list.dfs[[i]]))
}
list.mods
```